# How to efficiently get all inputs not of type="radio" on a form

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to select all inputs on my form that are not radio button type.

I have this:

```
$("input").not("[type='radio']")
```

Is this horribly inefficient? I'm selecting all inputs to start with.

Also I think read somewhere .not in jquery is often misused. Am I misusing it here? Is there a better way?

Comment: You can add a class in html to avoid this.

Comment: You are not misusing `.not()`. Can you include `html` of `<form>` at Question?

Comment: Seems like `$("input:not([type='radio'])")` _might_ be faster, but you'd have to test it to know for sure. Why are you concerned about the performance? Have you tested it and determined that its an issue?

Comment: There are 23 input types, if you check for all but radios, than it can't be faster. How many inputs you may have on page, 1000? Think even than you won't notice any difference. If you check [this post](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/), you will see that you already use fastest way.